# Flask/Python - Requests, make POST call, wait for response and make GET call using to fetch record of POST

Tags: python, flask

My application generates a UUID when I open a form and on submit it makes a POST call to my api passing this value which creates an event in my app with additional properties. I then want to call my events API passing the UUID value so my api will return a response where I will be able to see more properties.

I am receiving a 202 status code but on the response from my GET call I don't see the record. My guess was I wasn't waiting for the response but I was under the impression python requests will wait then execute the rest of the code.

I can make a call using postman passing the same values as in the GET call and I receive a response.

How can I ensure my app has waited enough time? I have tried `sleep(5)` which should be more than enough time but it till shows 0 records.

```
import requests, uuid, json, pymysql, datetime, time
from datetime import datetime
from random import randint
from time import strftime, sleep
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request, redirect, url_for, jsonify
from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, validators, \
    StringField, SubmitField

DEBUG = True
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'


class ReusableForm(Form):

###

@app.route('/alert', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def alert():
    form = ReusableForm(request.form)
    incident = uuid.uuid4()
    time = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

   if request.method == 'POST':
        impact = request.form['impact']     

        if form.validate():
            write_to_disk(impact)
            flash('{} {}'.format(impact))      
            
            url = "https://api/v1/"

            payload="{\"incident\":\"" + str(incident) + "\", \"Impact\":\"" + str(impact) + "\"}"
            headers = {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }

            response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
                    
            if response.status_code == 202:         
            
                sleep(3)
                inc_id = str(incident)
                print ("This is the second call")
                print (inc_id)
            
                url = "https://api/v1/events/" + inc_id + ",&embed=properties"
                
                print (url)

                payload={}
                headers = {
                            'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx='
                }

                response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
            
                response_dump = json.dumps(response.text, sort_keys = True, indent = 4, separators = (',', ': '))

                print (response_dump)
                   
        return redirect(url_for('updated'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have enough reputation to write a comment. Can you add a code for your GET endpoint in api? Cause I see that there is also some get parameters (by the way, `,&embed=properties` should be changed to `?embed=properties`.

And one advice:
You can pass your `payload` as a dict if you use json keyword argument. It will add appropriate header. So your code will look like that:

```
url = "https://api/v1/"

# usual dict now
payload={
         "incident" : str(incident), 
         "Impact": str(impact)
        }

response = requests.request("POST", url, json=payload)
```

Also: no need to pass any `data=payload` to your GET request